# Reaction mechanism of formation of salicylic acid with Phenol and carbon tetrachloride in basic medium?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, phenols

With classic Reimer-Tiemann reaction a variation is also given in my lecture notes which use carbon tetrachloride instead of chloroform. But to me, it seems like it would be just a substitution reaction rather than Reimer-Tiemann which proceeds through carbene. Given slow hydrolysis of $\ce{CCl4}$ how such a substitution reaction could be useful, even if we use $\ce{OH-}$ ? Or is there something else going on here?

Comment: You're right, as far as I know the $\ce{CCl4}$ reaction first occurs by the phenol (or phenoxide) acting as a nucleophile and substituting one of the chlorine atoms. The remaining three chlorine atoms are hydrolyzed and salicylic acid is formed

Comment: Will not the hydroxide be better-attacking species than phenoxide due to steric factors, if so we should expect a phosgene type intermediate.

Comment: That never occurred to me... I'm sorry, I'm not knowledgeable enough to provide a satisfying explanation.

Comment: Are you asking about abnormal RT reaction? https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/152344/bromochlorofluoromethane-as-a-reagent-in-riemer-tiemann-reaction/152354

Comment: @NilayGhosh the A V Gaonkar paper just point to the original German paper. I doubt that mechanisms in CCl4 and CHCL3 are different. How will CCl4 form the carbene ?

Comment: No time to answer but I am providing you some links where the mechanism of this reaction is given: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zbXqpZHX7wM https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n22TGgejl-8 https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-mechanism-of-Reimer-tiemann-reaction-of-phenol-and-carbon-tetrachloride-in-potassium-hydroxide (ofc the mechanism is different (no carbene is formed) and it is rather a variation if not an abnormality. So you can call whatever you want).

Comment: @NilayGhosh I don't think this is a correct mechanism or even the most probable, as I pointed out to TRC. The attack of OH- seems more probable than phenoxide.

Comment: @DeepakArya Want to make it an answer? :)

Comment: @NilayGhosh I haven't found any solid literature